# what is this error message trying to tell me? : Incorrect syntax near '100000'

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, data-binding, devforce

I am calling `Manager.SaveChanges()` and i get the following error.

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManagerSaveException' occurred in
>   IdeaBlade.EntityModel.dll

Additional information:

> Incorrect syntax near '100000'

How do I see what my save SQL syntax looks like? I have no clue what 100000 is. It happens on every record I try to save for this class. Other forms save properly.

Any suggestions on how to go about debugging this error.

I have stepped through the code and none of my properties have this value so I am not sure what it is referring to.

Comment: `Manager` is a DevForce object?

Comment: Manager is an instance of my EntityManager. i am not sure how in ideablade to view the query. from my client when the user clicks on the save button i call Repository.Save() with Repository being an instance of my Repository class. In my repository class, i call Manager.SaveChanges(). This method saves all unsaved changes in the entity manager.

Comment: The error message is probably coming from your DB provider and then bubbling up through EF and DevForce.  See if the debuglog on the EntityServer has more detailed error information.  On the client, you can also try drilling into inner exceptions to see if there's a more helpful error message buried in there.  Turning on a profiler to see the actual SQL could help too.

Comment: Adjust the <ideablade.configuration> section of your projects web.config file to enable logging, the query should be shown there.   
<ideablade.configuration xmlns="http://schemas.ideablade.com/2010/IdeaBladeConfig" version="6.00">
    <logging logFile="logs\DevForceLog.xml" shouldLogSqlQueries="true" archiveLogs="true" />

Comment: For a profiler, try SQL Profiler or EF Prof.  There's also information on how to get additional diagnostics in a DevForce app here - http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/debug.